# Controller not routing to correct view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

On our ASP MVC 3 intranet site we have two options for creating a new agent. The basic method is to simply go through the standard, out-of-the-box `Create` controller. Nothing too fancy here.

The second is to clone an agent that already exists. From the index of the controller, the user can select a "Clone" link that will send them to a different method named `CloneAgent` (we do this to keep the logic separate and the code cleaner/easier to maintain).

Both methods return to the same `Create` View. In the standard `Create` method the return statement is just a simple

```
return View(modelObj)
```

In the `CloneAgent` method the return statement isn't much more complicated

```
return View("Create", modelObj)
```

When I run the site locally, the `AgentClone` works fine, however the URL in the browser reads like so

```
http://localhost:2574/AgentTransmission/CloneAgent/0?agentId=%20%2011317710
```

When I run on the server I get the same URL however instead of the page loading I get one of our custom error message that the site has crashed.

Can someone help out with the proper `return` statement for the `AgentClone` method?

**Update:**

Forgot to mention - placed the `return` statement of the `AgentClone` method inside a `try` statement. I did not see an error message when I placed the code out on the server (still worked fine running locally) so I'm not sure where to look for the error.

**AgentClone**

```
    //GET
    public ActionResult CloneAgent(int id, int agentId = 0)
    {
        //Tax ID info
        ViewBag.FullSSN = Security.IsFullSsn(User);

        AgentTransmission clone;
        try
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                MonetToDssClient client = new MonetToDssClient();

                CloneMessage msg = client.CloneRequest("1234678");

                //TODO: make sure we are cloning appropriate fields
                clone = AgentTransmission.MapObject(msg.AgentInformation);

                EventLog.WriteEntry("Monet", "Clone complete", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO: make sure this method still applicable to add all agents
                clone = Clone(db.AgentTransmission.Find(id));
            }

            clone.FormattedReferenceNumber = ReferenceConversion.UnobAndFormat(clone.ReferenceNumber, "S");
            clone.ReferenceNumber = ReferenceConversion.ObfuscateReference(clone.ReferenceNumber);

            DisplayPrep();
            clone.SetDropDowns();

            EventLog.WriteEntry("Monet", "Heading back to Create", EventLogEntryType.Information);

            return View("Create", clone);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Monet", ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            string s = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }

    }
```

**MapObject Model Object method**

```
    //Use AutoMapper plugin to convert from MonetToDss namespace
    public static AgentTransmission MapObject(AgentClone source)
    {
        AgentTransmission destination = new AgentTransmission();

        //Create mapp between namespace models
        Mapper.CreateMap<AgentClone, AgentTransmission>();

        //Map AgentClone to AgentTransmission
        destination = Mapper.Map<AgentClone, AgentTransmission>(source);

        return destination;
    }
```

**View (header only)**

```
@model Monet.Models.AgentTransmission

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create new Agent";
}
```

**SECOND EDIT**

Here is the stack trace from the exception being thrown.

```
System.InvalidOperationException

System.InvalidOperationException: The view '~/Views/AgentTransmission/Create' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/AgentTransmission/Create
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass27.<>c__DisplayClass2c.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass27.<BeginInvokeAction>b__24(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
thrown in AgentTransmission/CloneAgent
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated since, as you can see from the pic below, the file path `Views/AgentTransmission/Create` exists (bottom of the stack trace shows this error was thrown in the AgentTransmission controller

[image]

Comment: Add an exception filter with some logging and find out what the error is.

Comment: Does "AgentId" exist in the modelObj? Is it a case where modelObj isn't model binding well?

Comment: @asawyer - sorry forgot to mention that in the post. I wrapped the `return` statement in a `try` block and didn't see an exception thrown. I think it's looking for an `AgentClone` view, which we don't have.

Comment: @Rikon - yes, "AgentId" exists on both modelObj's. They are both the same type.

Comment: That's not what I suggested, try adding an exception filter and logging the errors there.

Comment: Are you trying to change the view that the user sees, or are they actually supposed to go to the "Create" URL?

Comment: @Dave - they're supposed to go to the 'Create' URL (http://localhost:2574/AgentTransmission/Create)

Comment: @Dave - let me rephrase that (sorry): they user is supposed to be directed to the same View that is displayed at the localhost:2574/AgentTransmission/Create URL

Comment: @NealR - And the model that you're passing to that view is creating an error, but you can't see what the error is because of your site's custom error handling?

Comment: Any chance you can post the View for "Create"?

Comment: @Dave - I don't believe it's the model since this whole process works just fine when I run the machine locally through Visual Studio. I've noticed the URL via localhost is always short the root folder when compared to the URL needed to access the site from our DEV server  (ie localhost/AgentTransmission/Create vs                       <site name>/AgentTransmission/Create in DEV) so I think it's a matter of routing... which I'm relatively unfamiliar with.

Comment: @Dave - it's a very long form, i'll post the header though

Comment: Unless you've done something very odd with your routes or your Html.BeginForm statements, moving from localhost to a site on a dev server shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Also, if you have custom error pages coming up that are preventing you from getting a good picture of what's going on when something breaks, it's probably time to do something about that anyway.  My personal preference is Elmah - it provides a number of highly configurable options that allow you to review the "yellow screen of death" even if you're using custom error pages.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah.mvc/ is an MVC-friendly nuget package, and https://code.google.com/p/elmah/ should teach you how to configure it.

Comment: Just updated the post with the info from exception's stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

This just appears to be poorly written from the start.  You have commented above your ActionResult that this is clearly a get but you are returning to a "Create" view.

Whatever the case may be you should be passing your data in a ViewModel, ViewBag, or ViewData to the View and just returning the "View".

in this case the easiest way is to implement the ViewBag.

```
ViewBag.clone = clone;

return View("Create");
```

Then from this point it should return to the following URL

```
Http://localhost:2574/AgentTransmission/CloneAgent/Create
```

You can access your "clone" data in the create view as the ViewBag passes it 1 time to the view.

I would work on why the return isn't sending you to the right view before passing in any variables.

You should also be sure that the View exists and is not mistyped.  Views/AgentClone/Create.cshtml

**Edit:  You may also want to trim your AgentID. The URL has 2 spaces before its value,

```
http://localhost:2574/AgentTransmission/CloneAgent/0?agentId=**%20%20**11317710
```

Comment: A couple things: yes, this is a GET, however the user would like to clone some data from a record that already exists. Thus the helper method before we pass the user off to the Create page. Also, the URL I'm looking for would simply be `Http://localhost:2574/AgentTransmission/Create`. This page is currently working in production, so I'm simply struggling with routing to this view from a helper `ActionResult` method.

Comment: Again this is being poorly executed.  You are trying to do too many things with this method.  A new method to perform the clone when passing the id value of '0' should be utilized.  Breaking methods in controllers down will greatly increase your ability to troubleshoot issues like this.  From the code above have you been able to isolate the issue?  Does it work if you pass it an ID or does it only break when the ID = 0?